# Using JSONP to retrieve data from Twitter API

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter, google-chrome-extension, jsonp

I am trying to use jsonp to retrieve an embedded tweet (or several but let's start with 1) from the twitter api.  Cannot just use a get because of CORS, so I am trying jsonp, had it working just fine on a test page...

This code works, and gets the embed code just fine, when run on a website.

```
function myJSCallback() {
            console.log('called back');
        }


        var urlx = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?url=https://twitter.com/louisck/status/1209181253444030468';

        $.ajax({
            url: urlx,
            type: 'GET',
            jsonpCallback: 'myJSCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result.html);
            }
        });
```

However, if I run that exact code inside a chrome extension, I get an error.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property
>   'undefined' of object '#'

If I run it without the callback, I get a different error...

> actual error :
>   oembed.json?url=https://twitter.com/JackPosobiec/status/1238074823651274752&callback=jQuery34101717550445740914_1584065740386&_=1584065740387:1
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery34101717550445740914_1584065740386 is
>   not defined

Both versions work just fine when I run these in a regular website.  Neither work when I run them in a google chrome extension. I am trying to populate tweets on a page after it loads.  Just can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: That is not how JSONP works. Twitter would have to execute a predefined function you have written in JavaScript. You would not use AJAX at all. You would make your `<script>` tag target their Server. I'm getting what appears to be a 404 Error on that page.

Comment: Twitter does not support JSONP.

Comment: It does, here is an example of it working (Not in a chrome extension). https://jsfiddle.net/b4p87n12/